# Automatic services do not start

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, topshelf

I have a handful of console apps installed as services running under topshelf and if I install and run manually they work fine. However none automatically start even though the startup type is set to Automatic.

The apps are configured as follows:

```
HostFactory.Run(x =>
{
    x.Service<MyApp>(s =>
    {
        s.ConstructUsing(name => container.Resolve<MyApp>());
        s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
        s.WhenStopped(tc =>
        {
            tc.Stop();
            container.Dispose();
        });
    });

    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
    x.StartAutomatically();
    x.EnableServiceRecovery(rc => rc.RestartService(5));
});
```

The apps run under Win 2008 R2 and they are installed using a batch file executed as Admin. The batch file includes the following:

```
app.exe install --sudo
app.exe start
```

After executing the the batch file the services run as expected. However if I reboot they remain stopped.

The event log returns the same pair of events for each service:

> Event 7000: The  service failed to start due to the following error: 
>   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
>
> Event 7009: A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the  service to connect.

The only way to start the app after a reboot is to run `app.exe start` from an elevated command prompt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK i've fixed it. The service startup types were set to Automatic but i've changed them to Automatic (Delayed) and all now run properly on start-up.

Also i've modified the install batch files for future use:

```
app.exe install --delayed --sudo
app.exe start
```

Only a guess, but probably dependent on network services which might not be available.

Comment: You just saved me 100 years of digging in the garbage of information :)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely answer is that it's taking too long for the container to get created and resolved during start up when other stuff is happening on the machine. When you do it manually, nothing else is vying for resources. Can you defer some of the work done in your container until after creation & start? You can also request more time, but I don't recall that API off the top of my head.

Comment: Good point, there could be high CPU load as each app does some queue processing on Amazon SQS. On start-up the service checks the queue, downloads some objects from S3, processes them, uploads back to S3 and writes a new queue message. Although we're only dealing with a few dozen messages per hour, they are very lightweight on CPU resource. But the machine is a EC2 micro instance and possibly the spike could cause all 6 services to fail... although i'm not entirely convinced this is the cause. I'll try disabling all but one and see if I can get this to auto-start.

Comment: Still no joy. I took a new stock win2012 vm and installed a single service and tested its operation. After a reboot it remains stopped and the event log shows the above error. If I manually start the service to runs immediately.

Comment: If you can create a simple reproduction and bring it to the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/topshelf-discuss) then maybe we can help out a bit more. The symptom is still of the same problem, it's taking too long during start up. So the answer is somehow delay whatever is taking too long during start up but not later.